Does the measure of symmetric difference go to zero if the indicators converge pointwise and $\mu(A_n)\to A$?
Let $A_n$ and $A$ be measurable subsets with finite measure on the real line. Suppose
$$f_n:=\mathbb{1}_{A_n}\to \mathbb{1}_A=:f$$ pointwise almost everywhere and further
that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n| = \mu(A_n) \to \mu(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|.$$
I want to prove that, for any measurable subset $E$, that
$$\int_E |f_n-f| \to 0.$$
Here is my attempt:
We note that
$$|f_n - f| = |\mathbb{1}_{A_n} - \mathbb{1}_A| =\mathbb{1}_{A_n \Delta A},$$
thus
$$\int_E |f_n-f| = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{1}_{A_n \Delta A \cap E}= \mu(A_n \Delta A \cap E) \leq \mu(A_n\Delta A),$$
since $A_n \Delta A \cap E \subset A_n\Delta A$, using monotonicity of measure.
Life would be good if $\mu(A_n \Delta A) \leq |\mu(A_n)-\mu(A)|$ but in reality the opposite inequality is true:
$$|\mu(A_n)-\mu(A)|\leq \mu(A_n \Delta A),$$
so we need to either show that equality holds in this case or find a different method.
Equality holds certainly if $A_n\subset A$ or $A\subset A_n$. Maybe the pointwise convergence in this setting shows this is true for sufficiently large $n$ but I am not seeing it. Certainly, for the cases where either 1) $A_1 \subset A_2\subset \dotsc$ and $A=\cup_n A_n$ or 2) $A_1\supset A_2\supset \dotsc$ and $A=\cap_n A_n$, we are all good, but I am not sure if this exhausts all the possibilities implies by initial hypotheses.
Any ideas how to finish this off?

$\int(f-f_n)^{+} \to 0$ by DCT since $0 \leq (f-f_n)^{+}\leq f$ and $f$ is integrable. Also, $\int (f-f_n) \to 0$ and combining these two we get $\int(f-f_n)^{-} \to 0$. Finally, $\int |f-f_n|=\int(f-f_n)^{+}+\int(f-f_n)^{-} \to 0$. [This argument is called Sheffe's Lemma]. [All my integrals are over $\mathbb R$].

Nice, I knew about Sheffe's Lemma and this is probably the best proof. I should have wrote that I was trying to practice "the standard machine" (showing a result holds for indicators, for linear combinations of indicators, to all non-negative measurable functions, then all measurable functions), if no one else answers I will accept this.
